# Change of Variables in a Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was reading the answer to this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/187909/332763) and noted the following step in the derivation:

$$\text{Erf}(x) = 2\Phi(x\sqrt{2}) - 1$$
$$\implies \Phi(x) = \frac{1 + \text{Erf}(x/\sqrt{2})}{2}.$$

Where  $\Phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-z^2/2} \mathrm{d}z.$ is the CDF of the standard normal and $\text{Erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x e^{-t^2} \mathrm{d}t$ is the error function.

This step made me wonder, in general, if $f(ax+b) = g(x)$ does this imply that $f(x) = g((x-b)/a)$ for any function? If we let $y = ax+b$, then we can substitute and get $f(y) = g((y-b)/a)$ and then simply swap out the $y$ for $x$ for notational consistency, but this seems a bit loose to constitute a "proof" in my mind.

Comment: Provided every argument is in the domain of the respective function, this is nothing but giving different names to variables.